# Can Twig count the array lenght with a filter parameter

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an Account object that contains an one-to-many relation with the newsbrief members. In Twig a want to show the quantity of members. I know that I can show the quantity with the following code:

```
{{ account.mailList|length }}
```

Only the mailList contains also inactive members. With these members their field active is false. Is there a way to filter them out? Is this way of working slowing down the application?

Comment: You can write your own twig filter for this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop in twig:

```
{% set activeMailCount = 0 %}
{% for mail in account.mailList if account.mailList.active %}
    {% set activeMailCount = activeMailCount + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a method on the account entity that returns active members

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php
public function getActive()
{
    $count = 0;

    foreach($this->getMailList() as item) {
        if (item->isActive()) { // Assuming the newsbrief members are entities
            $count++            // with an $active property & isser().
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

and call that from Twig:

```
{{ account.getActive() }} # or {{ account.active }}
```